# Is it okay to omit the first "as" in "as adj. as" in informal speech?

Tags: adjectives, spoken-english, informal-language, adjective-phrases

I think I sometimes hear sentences like "Much as I think ..." or "Soon as he ...". I'm not certain, but when the "as adj. as" form comes at the beginning of the sentence, people sometimes omit the first as in informal speech. Did I hear correctly?

Comment: That 'as' is essential and cannot be removed, and I am not aware of any dialect that does so in speech. Possibly you misheard.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I was quite sure I head it *somewhere* (https://youtu.be/N6cfFnBNELs?t=62), although it seems not common?

Comment: See my answer below, which came after you accepted a previous one, but which I think may be clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems fine to me, if a bit informal (which is expected for speech). Here are some other examples:

> Much as we might hate it, negative ads work. (Blog comment)

> Soon as the sun rises, we'll be completely exposed. (TV: The Last Ship)

Found via COCA: [much](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=107870268), [soon](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=107870403).

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between the two usages you have identified:

> **Much as** is a normal, correct, not informal equivalent of 'even though'. The speaker in the video says 'Much as I think he's a knob, I
> quite like working with Jeremy [Clarkson]'. There is no missing first
> 'as'.
>
> [Much as (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/much-as)
>
> It should not be, although it sometimes is, confused with the similar
> 'as much as *something*' used to compare two things or ideas and
> expressing them to be equivalent. For example *I admire Michael for
> his good looks as much as for his integrity*.

> **As soon as** is an expression used to express that one thing follows another thing in time very soon, or instantly: *As soon as the thief
> saw the police officer, he started to run*. In casual or informal
> speech, the first 'as' is sometimes omitted.

Comment: "(As) Much as I think he's a knob, I quite like working with Jeremy" = "I quite like working with Jeremy as much as I think he's a knob". The speaker *is* comparing Jeremy being a knob and working with Jeremy.

Comment: @xiver77 - it doesn't work like that.

Comment: @xiver77 see [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/much-as): "much as" is an idiom meaning "although"

Comment: @Esther Wouldn't it make sense to think that the idiom came from shortening "as much as"? The sentence in Cambridge dictionary looks fine with "as" IMO - "(As) much as I would like to help you, I'm simply too busy at the moment."

Comment: @Esther It's comparing the willingness to help vs. the state of being too busy. When two conflicting things are comparable, a word like "although" would also fit, thus the meaning of the idiom.

Comment: @xiver77 It's possible that's where the idiom came from, but at this point it stands on its own and the omission of the first "as" is *not* informal or slang. Contrast with the second example, where omitting the first "as* *is* informal, since "soon as" is *not* an idiom of its own.

Comment: @xiver77 "_as much as_ I would like to help you, I'm too busy" is, strictly speaking, a [solecism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solecism).